# LDAP simulator/emulator for ubuntu or local LDAP server

Tags: ubuntu, ldap, emulation, simulator

Is there any ready solutions for simulating or emulating LDAP server functionality?

Or is it possible to install ldap server on ubuntu ( just for localhost)?
I cannot install real ldap server on my network if it is not jsut serving request from localhost..

So I think that simulated/emulated solution would be the best choice if available :)

Answer (score 1):

The UnboundID LDAP SDK provides classes to create an in-memory LDAP directory server which is fully functional.

#### see also

- [UnboundID LDAP SDK](https://www.unboundid.com/products/ldap-sdk/)
- [In-memory directory server example (my blog entry)](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/ldap-in-memory-directory-server-using-unboundid-ldap-sdk/)